# Display results of a query into a literal separated by commas

Tags: c#, sql, datareader

Currently I have a literal (called unitValues) that is displaying the results of a SQL query (which are units of measure). It works fine except, I would like to separate each unit of measure by a comma. Right now with how my code is set up, an extra comma is always added to the end. So, instead of:

value1, value2, value 3

I get:

value1, value2, value3,

Is there a way to prevent the extra comma from being placed at the end of the list of query results?

This is the code that gets the SQL data from the database and places it into the literal:

```
 protected void getUnits()
{
    try
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = null;
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [name] FROM [baird_UnitOfMeasure]", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cn.Open();
            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    unitValues.Text += (reader["name"].ToString()) +", ";
                }
             }
            cn.Close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        \\catch error
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Append the comma first rather than after (and bypass the first item):

```
protected void getUnits()
 {
   try
   {
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = null;
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [name] FROM [baird_UnitOfMeasure]", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cn.Open();
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(unitValues.Text)){
                  unitValues.Text += ", ";
               }
               unitValues.Text += reader["name"].ToString();
            }
         }
        cn.Close();

    }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      \\catch error
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly with your T-SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [name]
      FROM [baird_UnitOfMeasure]
      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS DelimList
      FROM [baird_UnitOfMeasure]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unitValues= unitValues.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: That won't work. You have to make that unitValues.TrimEnd(',', ' ')

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())  list.Add(reader["name"]);
unitValues.Text = list.Aggregate( (prev,cur) => prev + ", " + cur);
```

Comment: If you are going the List route, why not `unitValues.Text = String.Join(", ", list.ToArray());`